# jquery cloning datepicker & submitName IE bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm currently stuck on a stupid thing for hours and I can't see the light at the end of the tunnel.

I'm trying to clone a table in a form with autocompletion, datepicker & other stuff based on a HTML template. I saw that the datepicker function generates an unique ID so I've made the template without the class and I add it during cloning. The funny thing is that the datepicker shows up but get stuck when I try to select a date.

I've tried as well to change the name of the input contening the datepicker to be unique but it seems that IE has a funny bug of 'name' getting changed into 'submitName'

Any help & suggestions are welcome and appreciate. Here is my code below:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
        $(function() {
           $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
        });
    </SCRIPT>



   <button class="addLeg">Add Leg</button>
   <button class="delLeg">Remove Leg</button>
  </span>
<TABLE width="914px" border="0">
      <TR align="center">
        <TD width="23"></TD>
        <TD width="140" class="g1">Date</TD>
        <TD width="147" class="g1">Dep Time</TD>
        <TD colspan="2" class="g1">Routing</TD>
        <TD width="144" class="g1">Flight Time</TD>
        <TD width="142" class="g1">Pax</TD>
      </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE id="Leg" style="display:none" width="400px" border="0">
      <TR >
        <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="checkbox" class="delCheckLeg" name="chk"/></TD>
          <TD class="1"><INPUT type="text" id="tripdate" name="tripdate"></TD>
        <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="text" name="deptime"/></TD>
          <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="text" name="routingdep"/></TD>
          <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="text" name="routingarr"/></TD>
          <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="text" name="fttime"/></TD>
          <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="text" name="pax"/></TD>
      </TR>
</TABLE>
<div id="trip">
<TABLE id="Leg0" width="400px" border="0">
      <TR >
        <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="checkbox" class="delCheckLeg" name="chk"/></TD>
          <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="text" class="datepicker" id="tripdate0" name="tripdate0"></TD>
        <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="text" name="deptime"/></TD>
          <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="text" name="routingdep"/></TD>
          <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="text" name="routingarr"/></TD>
          <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="text" name="fttime"/></TD>
          <TD class="g1"><INPUT type="text" name="pax"/></TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var uniqueId = 1;
    var uniqueLeg = 1;
    $('.addLeg').click(function() {
        var copy = $('#Leg').clone();
        var formId = 'Leg' + uniqueLeg;
        copy.attr('id', formId );
        copy.removeAttr('style');

        copy.find(':input#tripdate').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('datepicker');
            $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });

            var dateid = 'tripdate' + uniqueLeg;
            $(this).attr('id', dateid ); 

                });

        $('#trip').append(copy);
        uniqueLeg++;  
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if you change the id of the element after you call datepicker it messes it up.

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/Xnjcs/2/). 
I just moved the following line

```
$(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
```

below

```
$(this).attr('id', dateid );
```

Also I added in changing the inputs name, i tried it in IE and it appeared to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! it works like a charm :) Only one little issue, the name/submitName issue in IE persists. I'm currently working with IE11. I'll figure out a solution for this. Thanks :)